# D-Link 2640u Router unfortunately update wrong firmware

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, firmware, adsl-router

I have this Dink router:
 DSL-2640U
 HW Veer: C2
 FW Veer: ME_2.01
I had tried to update firmware to this Indian firmware but it was not compatible with my modem (it's for  C4 version). I've seen a fatal error during updating firmware on my router and then it was reset. Now power led, internet led and 1 LAN led are turned on. I dint have access to admin panel (192.168.1.1). I had tried to reset my router with reset button but it did not work. I would appreciate who can help me to set new firmware on my router.

Comment: You might not be able to do anything.  Does it have a JTAG port?

Answer (score 0):

> Remove all cables from the router except for the power cable. Leave the power cable connected.
>        Get into a position in which you can be holding the reset button and have your other hand free.
>       Press and hold down the reset button. Hold this for 15 secs. Then remove the power from the router. When you remove the power continue holding down the reset button for another 30 secs.
>       Plug the power back into the router - still holding down the reset button. Wait for another 45 secs and then let go of the reset button.
>       Finally, wait for 10 secs and then remove the power again. Keep the router unplugged for 60 secs, then plug it back in.

[Source](http://www.its-on-the-internet-so-it-must-be-true.com/2012/11/faulty-dhcp-on-d-link-dsl-2640u-factory.html)